# onclick() event isnt working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is my code for a simple check list. When ever the user hovers over the item "take out the trash" the mouseover event works, however I want when the user clicks on the item "take out the trash" they will see the mouseover event and the onclick event beneath it.

There are no errors in the console, not sure what I am doing wrong. Any help would be grateful, thanks.

```js
$("#task1").mouseover(function() {
  $("#hidden").show();
});


$("#task1").mouseleave(function() {
  $("#hidden").hide();
});


$("#task1").on('click', function() {
  $("#hiddenExtend").show();
});

$("#task1").on("click", function() {
  $("#hiddenExtend").hide();
});
```

```css
#hidden,
#hiddenExtend {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="ui-state-default">
  <div class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox1" value="" />
    <div id="task1">
      <label>
    Take out the 
     trash
    <img src="img/edit.png" id="edit" alt="edit list">
       </label>
      <div id="hidden">
        12/11/17
      </div>
      <div id="hiddenExtend">
        Bins go out on Tuesday
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <li class="ui-state-default">
    <div class="checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox1" value="" />
      <div id="task1">
        <label>
  Take out the 
         trash
        <img src="img/edit.png" id="edit" alt="edit list">
           </label>
        <div id="hidden">
          12/11/17
        </div>
        <div id="hiddenExtend">
          Bins go out on Tuesday
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
```

Comment: You have duplicate IDs, so this is invalid.

Comment: @Xufox Invalid...yes, but should still technically work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need check whether the div is hidden or visible using the [is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/) method within an `if statement` for this to actually work:

```
var $hiddenExtend = $("#hiddenExtend");

$("#task1").on("click", function() {
  if ($hiddenExtend.is(":hidden")) {
    $hiddenExtend.show();
  } else {
    $hiddenExtend.hide();
  }
});
```

The same would apply towards your `mouseover/mouseleave` events:

```
var $hidden = $("#hidden");

$("#task1").mouseover(function() {
  if ($hidden.is(":hidden")) {
    $hidden.show();
  }
})
.mouseleave(function() {
  if ($hidden.is(":visible")) {
    $hidden.hide();
  }
});
```

Note that I also took the liberty to cache your two elements: `$("#hiddenExtend")` and `$("#hiddenExtend")` so the DOM doesn't have to repeatedly search for them on every event call.

As Xufox mentioned, while setting naming multiple elements with the same ID will still work, it's still prohibited by web standards. You might want to use classes instead.

Comment: This worked, thank you. Should I create an if statement for the mouseover events?

Comment: Yeah it would work in the same manner. I'll update my answer to reflect this. Don't forget to mark as correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
$(document).on('click','#task1',function(e){
    $('#hiddenExtend').slideToggle('slow');
});
```